# Supress OneDrive message banner in Excel using VBA

Tags: excel, vba, error-handling, onedrive

I am updating an Excel document with a lot of code, used by over 100 people in my office. It's all very advanced macro stuff, saving data to archives saved in shared drives.

My concern at the minute is the constant, pointless error messages from OneDrive. 'Upload Failed'. 'Upload Pending'. All this stuff is confusing our less tech-savvy staff, and they make no difference as we don't need to upload them/ update them on Onedrive.

Is there anyway to turn these notifications off? They appear in a yellow banner just below the formula bar. I would try and give some code a go myself before posting, but I don't even know where to begin, let alone if it's even possible.

Possible code turning off OneDrive sync, or just simply repressing the messages.

Any advice on this is appreciated

Comment: If you provide a snippet that causes the error, it will be easier to solve.

Comment: Have you tried [this](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/turn-off-disable-or-uninstall-onedrive-f32a17ce-3336-40fe-9c38-6efb09f944b0)?

Comment: @Sam Sorry, here is a picture of the message I wish to suppress. https://imgur.com/a/MztRBQm - It often happens when the workbook is opened, or when the macro is ran. As it is a OneDrive sync message, I am unsure what causes it as it isn't VBA or code I can access. Sorry it isn't clearer, had to get it from a colleague.

Comment: @Zac  Turning off or disabling OneDrive isn't an option. Thanks anyway